# Binding data to dropdown-list using array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following code:

```cs
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected String[] cat = { "Customer", "Librarian", "Book Seller" };
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {   
                DropDownList1.DataSource = cat;
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

I want to bind the array `cat` to `DropDownList1`. How do I do that?

Comment: I (heavily) edited your question to make it readable, also added the C# tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps you,

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        protected String[] cat = { "Customer", "Librarian", "Book Seller" };
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {   
                List<string> category = cat.ToList(); 
                DropDownList1.DataSource = category ;
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
}
```

Thanks!!!